# Laravel Passport get user Access Token after being issued

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel Passport to issue Bearers to the user once it's logged in and then be able to connect to the API (yes I know Sanctum might fit better my needs but I'm using Passport so don't even mention to switch to Sanctum), then on the Front-end, I store the user email and the Bearer in a cookie to use them later on for other queries and add the bearer to Axios Auth header though now I have a problem with my logic, maybe related to the fact that I don't know how to use Passport correctly in Nuxt.

I have queries for each page where I send the user email in a post request and they return back a mix of global info and user info.

Yes, my endpoints are already behind an auth middleware but I just send a Bearer Token to allow the endpoint to be queried with any data, there is no prevention to ask for User B info from User A.

How can I use prevent the user to send a different email and get another user's info?

This is how I issue an access token:

```
$token    = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;
```

there is a way to do something like this?

```
$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
// E.g. user@mail.com  ...

// Get the user Access Token
$userToken    = $user->getAccessToken;
// E.g. someBerareText

// check if the User Access Token match with the one send in the request
// if they don't match throw a 401
if ($userToken !== $request->header('Authorization')) {
   return response()->json([ "error" => "Not Authorized" ], 401);
...

// E.g. $request->header('Authorization') it's SomeOtherBearer because he
// requested info for user@mail.com but the $request->header('Authorization')
// belong to otheruser@othermail.com
```

The user can still send the same request but with User B's email and see other info that doesn't belong to him, so how can I check if the email in the `$request` belongs to the user that's actually logged in?

some way to decode the access token and check if it really belongs to the user or not?

Comment: But the user you are fetching from auth::user will always belong to the token, what is the use case for this? or try to describe the problem further, why is this needed?

Comment: as I mentioned before every page in the front-end send the user email to get a mix or user's info and page related into, but that means that if user A sends a request for the same page but with user B email it will have User B info that's the problem.
My middleware check if the request contains an authorization bearer but that doesn't prevent asking for info for another user.
The idea's to get the user's Bearer, get the user's info and check if it matches the email sent in the request

Comment: But then User::where('email', $request->email)->first()->is(Auth::user()) not work checks your request email against the user authenticated? Auth::user is loaded excatly as you describe, thou it happens in the guard so not as easy to call when you need it.

Comment: I just added an example in the code to make it more clear

Comment: also the FE it's completely separate from the BE, Laravel act only as an API, and the FE it's in Nuxt in a different container

Comment: And? still why does my example not work.

Comment: Sorry, I thought `Auth::user()` was available only when you work with Laravel FE, is that available also when using Laravel as an API? how does it know who's the auth user? what does it use to check it?

Comment: I made an answer, it seems like things are cleared out and tryed to explain how laravel actually does load the user from the bearer token :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Laravel Passport` is set up as the guard, it will fetch the user from the bearer token, the logic can be seen in the [TokenGuard.php](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/ab9e2045e0d8649cd84de411d0332bdd5fe763a3/src/Guards/TokenGuard.php#L145) class in Passport. It actually does the same as you want to achieve.

So the authentication works different compared to the guard used. Therefor Passport requires you to change the guard. This is the deciding factor how `Laravel` differentiate Authentication and for that matter how the `Auth::user()` is loaded.

```
'guards' => [
    ...

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

This means that you can check if the user is the correct authenticated with the model function `is()` that compare if the models are the same.

```
User::where('email', $request->email)->first()->is(Auth::user())
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work, I log in via postman -> I copy the Bearer and send it in the new request with the correct email and I don't have anything back doesn't matter which email I use. My `guards` are OK I just noticed that I have an extra field `'hash'  => false,`
just to make sure I'm loading the correct one it's this one right? `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Comment: what does dd(Auth::user()) returns?

Comment: it doesn't return anything

Comment: doesnt return anything is a complex statement in programming, it returns null?

Comment: from Postman, I can see literally anything, an empty 200 response I assume it can be null even though it doesn't say null

Comment: BTW this is the base from where I'm working on in the project https://github.com/sebalaini/laravel_docker-compose the repo I'm working it's private but decided to make the base public

Comment: dd(); will give an response

Comment: sorry, my bad it actually working I just had to comment out a couple of returns and return the `dd()` directly. thank you :)
Just to noted that `is()` return a boolean so I can use that code in a statement.